# Messages randomly arrive with missing data when having more than 1 consumer to a topic

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-integration

I'm working with:
ActiveMQ 5.3.1
Spring 3.1.0
Spring Integartion 2.2.0

I'm having a problem that when I have more than 1 consumer to a topic, some of the messages (randomly) are missing text data.
This is the text needed to convert the JMS message to an integration message (payload).

It doesn't happen when I have only one consumer.

I tried to add logs to the spring classes and I see that on the consumer side, the `ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener` prints the JMS message and the text is `null`.

I also tried to add logs on the producer side, but it seems as the JMS message is being sent correctly (with the text not null).

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you using CachingConnectionFactory?

Comment: How about to upgrade Spring Framework to 4.0 and Spring Integration to 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded ActiveMQ to version 5.6.0 and it solved the problem!!